# SignalR - Webfarm with Sticky Sessions scenario

Tags: signalr, session-state, sticky, web-farm

Is it possible to use SignalR in a webfarm with Sticky Sessions? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No, Yes it's possible. No, not right now because the scaleout is being rewritten for 1.1 (which is in a few weeks). When it's out you'l be able to use SignalR on sticky or non sticky sessions (it's irrelevant really) using Sql server, service bus or redis. There'll be more info about it on http://asp.net/signalr in weeks to come.